# Robocopy And Using Variables In Powershell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to set up a robocopy job in powershell that copies files to a destination directory using an array and a variable. I want it to use a specific value based on the current date.

Here is powershell variable I have created to get the current date:

`$FYDate=Get-Date -Format "MM-MMM"`  (Note:I just want the current Month)

Output:

```
04-Apr
```

And here is the array that I have created in powershell:

```
$FYDates = "FY20\01-Oct", "FY20\02-Nov", "FY20\03-Dec", "FY20\04-Jan", "FY20\05-Feb", "FY20\06-Mar", "FY20\07-Apr", "FY20\08-May", "FY20\09-Jun", "FY20\10-Jul", "FY20\11-Aug", "FY20\12-Sep"
```

And here is the output:

```
FY20\01-Oct
FY20\02-Nov
FY20\03-Dec
FY20\04-Jan
FY20\05-Feb
FY20\06-Mar
FY20\07-Apr
FY20\08-May
FY20\09-Jun
FY20\10-Jul
FY20\11-Aug
FY20\12-Sep
```

What I would like to accomplish is have robocopy use the `$FYDate` variable and based off of that value, use one of the values in the `$FYDates` array.

Here is the robocopy script line I have so far:

```
ROBOCOPY D:\home\test_sftp\inbox C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\FY20\"$FYDate" *sams* /E`
```

This does create the directory named 04-Apr so I know the `$FYDate` variable works. How do I pair the two?

Example:
If Value is 04-Apr I want robocopy to use FY20\07-Apr as the destination directory. I just do not know how to script robocopy to use those two variables to copy the files to that location.

Answer (score 0):

my original solution almost totally missed the point - fiscal year offset of the month numbers. this one seems to do what the Questioner intended.

this builds the path using the builtin `Join-Path` cmdlet. that handily deals with path delimiters for you.

what the code does ...

- defines the FY month offset
- defines the root of the destination path
- iterates thru 12 months of the current year
- creates a temp date to work with
- derives the offset month number
- corrects for "there aint no such thing as a 13th month"
- shows the temp date
- builds & shows the destination path

that seems to do what you need done. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
$FYMonthOffset = 3
$RootDestPath = 'C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams'

foreach ($Index in 1..12)
    {
    # create some dates to work with
    $TempDate = Get-Date -Month $Index

    $FY_MNumber = $TempDate.Month + $FYMonthOffset
    # does the year need to change when the month wraps around?
    if ($FY_MNumber -gt 12)
        {
        $FY_MNumber -= 12
        }

    'Test date = {0, 24}' -f $TempDate.ToString('MM-MMM')
    Join-Path -Path $RootDestPath -ChildPath ('{0:00}-{1}' -f $FY_MNumber, $TempDate.ToString('MMM'))
    ''
    }
```

output ...

```
Test date =                   01-Jan
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\04-Jan

Test date =                   02-Feb
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\05-Feb

Test date =                   03-Mar
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\06-Mar

Test date =                   04-Apr
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\07-Apr

Test date =                   05-May
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\08-May

Test date =                   06-Jun
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\09-Jun

Test date =                   07-Jul
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\10-Jul

Test date =                   08-Aug
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\11-Aug

Test date =                   09-Sep
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\12-Sep

Test date =                   10-Oct
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\01-Oct

Test date =                   11-Nov
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\02-Nov

Test date =                   12-Dec
C:\temp\test\UoT_Working\sams\03-Dec
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The issue is that the actual files need to be copied to the corresponding month directory based on today's month. Example: if today's month is 04-Apr ($FYDate=Get-Date -Format "MM-MMM"), the files would need to go to 07-Apr directory (array variable I created). Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: what is the relationship between the current date and the fiscal year date? it looks like you have a 3 month offset where Jan becomes 04-Jan. that looks like a lookup table OR a simple addition.

Comment: Correct. I may be trying to over engineer this. If there is a simpler way to take Todays date and change the Month number (04)  to (07) but leave the Month name (Apr) I can add 3 months to the date: '$FyDate=(Get-Date).AddMonths(3)' But of course it changes both.

Comment: @JT-66 - please take a look at the rewritten code. i think it now does what you _actually asked_ ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you just want a hashtable:

```
$h = @{}
$h["04-Apr"] = "FY20\07-Apr"
$h["05-May"] = "FY20\08-May"
…
```

then in your robocopy you'd use

```
$h.$FYDate
```

or something like that.